# Is “egotisticality” a word?

Tags: word-choice

I wanted to use the word “egotisticality” in an essay, but I realized that I didn’t know whether it was a word. I looked it up and got nothing that said it was a word, but I received no definitive “no” answer.

**Is “egotisticality” a word?**

Comment: I would say it's a word, formed using the customary rules for suffixes.

Comment: To mean what, egotism?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if you can't find it in any common reference then you have an answer.

Comment: It is a 'word' in the sense that it is bound by spaces and used in your question. However, if you have looked for it without success in several dictionaries then you can certainly say that it is not an 'established' word.

Comment: @Shoe - It does show up in several online dictionaries, but not any "authoritative" ones.

Comment: Absence of evidence is not evidence of absence. Dictionary-makers don't explicitly include every word which could theoretically be constructed by adding prefixes or suffixes to a root word.

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=156447690527&id=136515514034

Answer (score 1):

According to the Merriam-Webster Dictionary, "egotisticality" is not a word.

Egotism is the quality that egotistical people possess.

Comment: If "egotisticality" is not in the Merriam-Webster dictionary, that just means that it isn't in the dictionary: it doesn't constitute a claim that "*egotisticality* is not a word". All dictionaries are incomplete.

Comment: Its showing in a Google search probably indicates that it shouldn't be in any respectable dictionary. At the moment.

Comment: Your statement is wrong. MW does not say that it is not a word.